# "At schedule" vs. "by schedule" vs. "on schedule"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, prepositions

Let's assume that I wash my car every Saturday at noon. How do I say it using the word *schedule*:

> I wash my car at/by/on schedule.

**Update:** It's not about doing something on a regular basis. It's about doing something on schedule — at an exactly defined day and time every week. If I say "I wash my car regularly", it simply means that I don't forget to wash my car, but doesn't imply I do it every time at the same time.

Comment: something like an isochronal car-wash schedule.

Comment: It's not about *schedule* -- it's *regular* / *habitual.* Do not say  *schedule* instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *to a schedule* to mean you have a preplanned date/time when you will wash your car.

> I wash my car to a schedule.

A more wordy way to say it would be

> I wash my car in accordance with my/the/a schedule.

Answer (score 1):

I wash my car every Saturday *like clockwork*.

Comment: I am not my car. Even on Saturdays)

Comment: okay... corrected :)

Answer (score 0):

*On schedule* is the right definition. It sounds a bit unusual for the habit of washing your car. It refers more to prefixed arrangements that have to be carried out on the agreed time.

For your habit I'd say:

I am used to washing my car every Saturday at noon.

Comment: I don't want to put emphasis on when I wash it. Just wanna say "regularly", but with meaning that I do it at the very same time each week.

Comment: Isn't "on schedule" equals to saying "on time" and not "regularly"?

Comment: by "at the very same time each week" do you mean the same day or/and same time??

Comment: @vickyace - the same day, the same time

Comment: isochronal car-wash schedule

Answer (score 0):

[Habitual](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/habitual): Being such by habit.

Or any of its subsequent synonyms (constant, persistent, continual, continuous, perpetual, nonstop, recurrent, repeated, frequent).

> I habitually wash my car according to schedule (every Saturday at noon).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'on schedule', I would say 'on `a` schedule'

*I wash my car **on a schedule***

*On a schedule* implies that you have some schedule for washing you car.

Answer (score 0):

Consider "[on time](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/on+time)" and "on a [timely](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/timely) manner (or basis)."

> *I wash my car every Saturday **on time***.
>
> *I wash my car every Saturday **on a timely basis***.

Comment: I'm using in my trello board like this: "Running (On Time)".